# clock watchdog timeout when starting Nox Player

Tags: android-emulator, bsod

When I start Nox Player, the loading bar freezes at 45% and Windows shows a blue screen of death with an error _CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT. My system settings:
AMD Ryzen 7 5700G
Gigabyte x570 UD rev 1.0
Kingston Fury Renegade 3600
Be quiet 500W
BIOS updated to version F37c. the Amd Adrenalin has the latest drivers installed

Answer (score -1):

Open BIOS, turn on virtualization